# Provisioning list with different URL than internal list name

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, url

can I provision a list instance in SharePoint 2013 that has following configuration:

```
Name:"MyCustomList"
Title:"My Custom List"
Url:"Lists/List1"
```

Is this possible? I tried just changing the URL attribute of a list, but then I got multiple errors of SharePoint not finding things. So is this even possible? I know I could use C#, but a purely declarative approach would be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible, in the `Url` you need to specify the site-relative url.

Try it as below:

```
<ListInstance Title="My Custom List"
              OnQuickLaunch="TRUE"
              TemplateType="100"                    
              Url="Lists/List1"
              Description="MyCustomList desciption">
</ListInstance>
```

Reference - [List Instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms478860.aspx)

FYI - Lists don't have internal name or name, they only have Title, Description(optional), URL(rootfolder) and TemplateType (like custom list, doc lib, calendar etc)  . So, yes it's perfectly valid for title and URL to be different.